# Azure Application Insights Kusto Query - do I need to specify tables? Is there no shortcut for "all tables"?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, kusto-explorer

Is there a way to specify "union of all tables" in Kusto? In particular with Azure Application Insights?

Or do I have to specify and union the tables?

```
union isfuzzy=true
    availabilityResults,
    requests,
    exceptions,
    pageViews,
    traces,
    customEvents,
    dependencies
| where timestamp > datetime("2022-04-20T20:38:00.812Z")
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
*
| where...
```

or

```
all
| where...
```

Answer (score 1):

the `union` operator supports the `*` notation, so if you must - you can run `union prefix* | where ...`, or `union * | where ...`